# android Bluetooth BLE connection flow

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Bluetooth connection application

I have written service which scan devices.

When I  get device on `onLeScan()` **callback**
Phone service add to list & monitored when it last time was visible and checking some characteristic and that's all now app waiting for user interaction.

1) I should after read data from characteristic call on blutetoothGatt `disconnect() or close()?`

Now, I calling `disconnect()`, device was disconnected but suddenly after call again I recieve it on `onLeScan()` callback

2) Where I should react for connection issues in onConnectionStateChange or skip it and do some after receive device on `onLeScan()` callback ?

Comment: discover? you mean scan?

Answer (score 0):

First, connect to your BLE.
Then, discover your services using the following code.

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattcallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
                                        int newState) {
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            mStatus = newState;
            mConnGatt.discoverServices();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            mStatus = newState;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { 
             setInterval.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

After callBack, set the UUID to the button. I'm using setInterval button.

```
@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    for (BluetoothGattService service : gatt.getServices()) {
        if ((service == null) || (service.getUuid() == null)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (BleUuid.IR_SERVICE.equalsIgnoreCase(service
                .getUuid().toString())) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    setInterval.setEnabled(true);
                }

            });
            setInterval.setTag(service
                    .getCharacteristic(UUID
                            .fromString(BleUuid.WRITE_TIME)));
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            }
        });
    }}
```

Then, read and write classes

```
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            if (BleUuid.CHAR_MANUFACTURER_NAME_STRING
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(characteristic.getUuid().toString())) {
                final String name = characteristic.getStringValue(0);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        setInterval.setText(name);
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                      BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Then I used a click listener to send data to BLE.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.setinterval:
            if ((v.getTag() != null)
                    && (v.getTag() instanceof BluetoothGattCharacteristic)) {
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch = (BluetoothGattCharacteristic) v
                        .getTag();
                String hr = String.valueOf(tp.getCurrentHour());
                String min = String.valueOf(tp.getCurrentMinute());
                String interval = new StringBuilder().append(hr).append(min).toString();
                ch.setValue(interval);
                if (mConnGatt.writeCharacteristic(ch)) {
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.toast_interval +interval, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }}
```

Comment: I know its not an accurate data . But this example may help you.